# How cnn layers connect in keras?

Tags: keras, convolution

Is there anyone who knows how cnn layers connect in keras?

```python
## layer #1
inputs = Input((img_rows, img_cols, 5, 1), name='inputs')  # shape (?, 192,192,5,1)

conv1_1 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs) # shape (?,192,192,5,32)
conv1_1 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1_1)
pool1_1 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 1))(conv1_1)
drop1_1 = Dropout(0.2)(pool1_1)

## layer #2
conv2_1 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop1_1) # shape(?,96,96,5,64)
conv2_1 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv2_1)
pool2_1 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 1))(conv2_1)
drop2_1 = Dropout(0.2)(pool2_1)

## layer #3
conv3_1 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop2_1) # shape(?, 48,48,5,128)
conv3_1 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3_1)
pool3_1 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 1))(conv3_1)
drop3_1 = Dropout(0.2)(pool3_1)
```

For example, the shape of conv1_1 layer is (?,192,192,5,32) and the shape of conv2_1 layer is (?,96,96,5,64). In this case, 32 and 64 indicate the number of filters(or output channels) in each cnn layer. At this point, how can I estimate the number of features or number of nodes from layer #1 to layer #2?

Comment: a bit unclear to me here Tom, I would love to help but what exactly are you trying to do. Can you give us a requirement?

Comment: Many of the terms you are  using are ill-defined in this context, like number of features, number of nodes, even how the layers are connected. Can you tell us more what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am sorry, it is very difficult to explain my question due to my language problem. Anyway, the output shape after conv1_1 is (?, 192,192,5,32) and the output shape after conv2_1 is (?, 96,96,5,64) in this case we ignore maxpooling and dropout. my question is how 64 nodes in the output of conv2_1 make from 32 node in previous conv1_1? In other words, how connected between conv1_1 and conv2_1? I want to know the relationship between conv1_1 and conv2_1. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> how can I estimate the number of features or number of nodes from
>   layer #1 to layer #2?

If you mean number of weights, if you define your layer as l (`l = Conv3D(...)` etc) you can access kernel and biase weights, and get its shape. For the number of features you can do this with layer output (you'd need to define separate variables for that, and not just use one name as you did).